# TypeScript Definition manager error on query

Tags: typescript, angular, tsd

Following the [Angular 2 5 minutes quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html), I wanted to install 
Angular 2 definitions (for TypeScript compiler and my IDE) provided by DefinitelyTyped using their package manager, [tsd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsd).

So I typed this command on a terminal

```
tsd query angular2 --action install
```

And all I got is the following error

```
>> tsd 0.5.7
_http_client.js:73
    throw new TypeError('Request path contains unescaped characters.');
          ^
TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters.
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:73:11)
    at TunnelingAgent.exports.request (http.js:49:10)
    at TunnelingAgent.createSocket (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tsd/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:117:25)
    at TunnelingAgent.createSecureSocket [as createSocket] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tsd/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:184:41)
    at TunnelingAgent.addRequest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tsd/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:80:8)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:154:16)
    at Object.exports.request (http.js:49:10)
    at Object.exports.request (https.js:136:15)
    at Request.start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tsd/node_modules/request/request.js:582:30)
    at Request.end (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tsd/node_modules/request/request.js:1226:28)
```

After some search, I check my settings (npm, tsd and git) for proxy, which is well set so it is not that. I'm using tsd version **0.5.7**.

Have you got any idea on how to fix this ?

**Edit 05/18:**

A simple query like `tsd query angular2` returns me the same error, and `tsd install angular2` is not a valid command, calling it returns me result of `tsd --help` telling me that I must run `tsd query [pkgname] --action insall` to install a package.

**Edit upgrading to 0.6.0:**

After upgrading to version 0.6.0 that had just been released, no problem anymore.

Both `tsd install [pkg]` and `tsd query [pkg] --action install` work like  a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using tsd for a few months now and have not used `--action install` off of a query result

I have been using version: tsd 0.6.0-beta.5 to handle my querying and installations via:

> To search for a definition I use:
> **tsd query [pkg name]**
>
> To install a definition I use:
> **tsd install [pkg name]**

I use `tsd install angular2 --save` to setup my angular2 project in conjunction with `tsd init` which creates a tsd.json to track all of my definition dependencies and keep the typings files out of version control

Comment: I'll give it a try back to work and tell you, thanks !

Comment: Hi, after testing `tsd query` give me the same error and `tsd install` returns me a *command not found* error. Help tells me to use `tsd query [pkg] --action install` to install a package. For information, I'm using tsd 0.5.7

Comment: There may have been a change in versions, I am using version `tsd 0.6.0-beta.5` and it appears to have been added after the release you are using.

Comment: Yep you're right, I edited my question earlier. Can you edit your answer to point the fact that tsd needed to be updated so that I can accept it ?